# c# dictionary automatically break the for loop,

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, dictionary, break

```
Dictionary<double, Tuple<int,int>> dictionary = new Dictionary<double, Tuple<int,int>>();

for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
    for (int j = i+1; j < x.Length; j++)
    {
        double weight = Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((x[i] - x[j]), 2) + Math.Pow((y[i] - y[j]), 2)), 2);
        string edges = i + "-" + j + "-" + weight;
        listBox1.Items.Add(edges);
        Tuple<int, int> tuple = new Tuple<int, int>(i, j);
        dictionary.Add(weight, tuple);
    }

var list = dictionary.Keys.ToList();
list.Sort();

foreach (var key in list)
{
    string a = dictionary[key].Item1 + "--" + dictionary[key].Item2 + "--> " + key.ToString();
    listBox2.Items.Add(a);
}
```

I am trying to store some values in dictionary. But in the for loop suddenly its break with uncomplete values. There is no error message. 
When i comment out "dictionary.Add(weight, tuple);" listbox is showing all data i want.

Comment: What is `x` exactly?

Comment: it is array of x-y coordinates system that x values of all x points

Comment: How can the listbox possibly show all the data you want, when you comment out `dictionary.Add(weight, tuple);`? The listbox is populating from the dictionary, which will be empty if you make that comment.

Comment: listbox1 in the for loop is filling all data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k(v=vs.110).aspx) to a `Dictionary` a key which was already added, it'll throw a `DuplicateKeyException`. This is highly likely since you're rounding your double, resulting in several which will become the same value.

Assuming by the use of a `ListBox` that you're using this in a UI event (Forms,  WPF, or otherwise) I would say it probably *is* throwing an exception, but something else is catching that exception and moving on.

When adding to a dictionary, you should check if the key already exists, and handle appropriately.

If you want to override the value, keep in mind that [`this[TKey key]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx) will *not* throw an exception when adding a new item. Thus

```
// dictionary.Add(weight, tuple);
dictionary[weight] = tuple;
```

If you want to skip past a value that's already present, check for [`ContainsKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(weight)) 
    dictionary.Add(weight, tuple);
```

Comment: i am trying to save x to y with z distance. So when z distances will come same value it will  always break . is there any solution to add same key value data

Comment: Not directly. You would need to change to a different data, first thing to consider is a `Dictionary<double, List<Tuple<int, int>>>` - you might also want to think of reversing the key-values here (`Tuples` are valid as keys) - this all amounts, however, to a large amount of design change.